# Earlier Query: Saving Channel List Into Memory Botnet - Response

Tags: c, string, irc

Earlier somebody posted a question regarding a bot they were developing for IRC.

They mentioned that upon sending the server a command to list channels the server would reply with raw data of all the channels and at the end of that list would be `ENDOFLIST`. They also said that they do not know the actual length of the data being sent and cannot rely purely on a function like `strstr` because if a user named a channel `ENDOFLIST` the string would terminate there. They then asked if it was possible to determine when the true `ENDOFLIST` came in the buffer of raw data they had.

My idea was just to iterate through the data until the very last instance of `ENDOFLIST` was found, and then just go off the location of that final instance. Before I could post my answer the person who asked the question deleted it, but I am still wondering if my solution is a viable one.

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*function I wrote for myself a while back to find substrings*/
int strsbstr(const char *str, const char *sbstr)
{
    char *sbstrlc;

    if(!(strcmp(str, sbstr))) return 0;
    if(!(sbstrlc = strstr(str, sbstr))) return -1;
    return (int) (sbstrlc - str);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int index = 0, location = 0;
    char *string;

    if(!(string = malloc(37))) return 0x00;
    strcpy(string, "FOOBARENDOFLISTENDOFLISTENDOFLISTFOO");  //string contains "ENDOFLIST" three times
    index = strsbstr(string, "ENDOFLIST");                   //index holds position of first occurence of "ENDOFLIST" within the string
    while(index != -1)                                       //loop through the rest of the string until the final "ENDOFLIST" is found
    {
        location = index + location + strlen("ENDOFLIST");
        index = strsbstr(string + location, "ENDOFLIST");
    }
    /*
    the variable 'location' now holds the position of the final char of the last occurence of "ENDOFLIST" within the string
    and 'location - strlen("ENDOFLIST")' would yield the position of the first char of the last occurence of "ENDOFLIST" 
    within the string
    */
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure many of you who frequent the `C` section of this site have seen this post earlier today. I just wanted to get some input if this would solve the problem that the asker was having, and if it's viable.

Even thinking of it practically I'm almost 100% sure that IRC channels cannot have the same name anyway so the loop might not even be needed. It should only have to check if "ENDOFLIST" occurs in the string once more after the first time right?

Comment: I doubt that `ENDOFLIST` is a valid irc channel descriptor. The people who created the protocol have surely been smart enough to consider that.

Comment: I don't remember much of IRC, so the channel-list command, does it return the channels on one line, or one channel per line? If a single long line, is the `"ENDOFLIST"` token on a separate line?

Comment: According to the OP it wasn't which I thought was strange too. However, assuming that the protocol was not smart enough to considor that I wonder if this would have helped OP it at all.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg not sure but I have a feeling the data MUST be deliminated some how, but OP did not mention anything about deliminators so I excluded them from my answer.

Comment: Does it say anything in the available RFC's? (They are listed in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irc).)

Comment: The RFC about the irc protocol does not know anywthing about an `ENDOFLIST` token. instead, it says about the list command: The list message is used to list channels and their topics.  If  the
   <channel>  parameter  is  used,  only  the  status  of  that  channel
   is displayed.  Private  channels  are  listed  (without  their
   topics)  as channel "Prv" unless the client generating the query is
   actually on that channel.  Likewise, secret channels are not listed

Comment: @KeithMiller go sit in a corner and RTFM... EDIT: sorry if that sounded harsh, but it's not like we live in a world without search engines. :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin No need to be rude, I just asked a quetion. I don't know much about the IRC protocol I just asked if what I posted was a viable solution. Or are you saying that because RFC is a manual? :/ and I did google RFC Request for Comments, did a google for IRC RFC and got a sort of instruction page still not sure what RFC stands for or if it's particular to IRC etc.

Comment: RFC is an abbreviation for "Request for Comment". that's how internet standards are made. A group of people sits down and writes a lengthy document about an internet protocol or whatnot, and publishes that as an RFC. then more people get involved and discuss and improve, until the RFC becomes standard. Because of the level of detail, RFCs are usually good sources for this kind of questions, or, for example, if you wanted to implement a specific protocol in a client / server allication. HTTP is a very popular protocol that is standardized by a ducument that evolved from an RFC.